# Ajax to get multiple value in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

Display ajax response into input field but it is not working

**HTML CODE:**

```
<html>
<select name="class_id" class="form-control" data-validate="required" id="class_id" 
data-message-required="<?php echo get_phrase('value_required');?>" 
onchange="return et_student_fees(this.value)">                 
<div class="form-group">
<input id="admission" value=""  type="text" class="form-control" name="admission-fee" >                     
<input id="tuition" type="text" class="form-control" name="tuition-fee" value="">                       
<input id="exam" type="text" class="form-control" name="exam-fee" value=""></div>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">

function get_student_fees(class_id)
{

    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?admin/get_student_fees/' + class_id ,
        success: function(response)
        {                           
                var len = response.length;

            if(len > 0){
            // Read values
            $('#admission').val(response.admissionfee);
            $('#tution').text(response.tutionfee);
            $('#exam').text(response.examfee);

            }else{
            $('#admission').text('');
            $('#tution').text('');
            $('#exam').text('');
            }
        }
    });
```

}

**Controller:**

```
function get_student_fees($class_id)
{
    $fees = $this->db->get_where('fees' , array('class_id' => $class_id
    ))->result_array();

    foreach ($fees as $row) {
    $response = array();
    $data['admissionfee'] = $row['admissionfee'];
    $data['tutionfee'] = $row['tutionfee'];
    $data['examfee'] = $row['examfee'];
    array_push($response , $data);
    }
   echo json_encode($response);

   }
```

using ajax to get value from controller,Can anyone please help me to return Multiples values and show these value into text feilds

Comment: Your input-id is `tuition` and you have misspell it in your ajax code i.e: `#tution` ,change that accordingly .Also ,check what does `response` have in it .

Comment: changed that, response.admissionfee has undefined  but response have all values

Comment: Would you please check your callback function name at this point `onchange="return et_student_fees(this.value)` because your function name is `get_student_fees()`  but you're calling it as `et_student_fees()`

Comment: corrected, but still same problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Hope this helps

```js
function get_student_fees(class_id){
    $.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?admin/get_student_fees/' + class_id ,
    success: function(response){
    var len = response.length;
        if(len > 0){
        // Read values
        var obj= jQuery.parseJSON(response);
        $('#admission').val(obj.admissionfee);
        $('#tution').text(obj.tutionfee);
        $('#exam').text(obj.examfee);
        }else{
        $('#admission').text('');
        $('#tution').text('');
        $('#exam').text('');
        }
     }
   });
```

Comment: appreciate that but this technique isn't solved the problem. suggest more please.